# difference between using a template function type and std::function

Tags: c++, c++17

I am curious as to why `a2` is fine, but `b2` won't compile:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    A(std::function<void(int)>&& func) : f(std::move(func)) {}

    std::function<void(int)> f;
};

template <class F>
class B {
public:
    B(F&& func) : f(std::move(func)) {}

    F f;
};

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    auto f = [a](int b){std::cout << a+b << '\n';};
    A a1([a](int b){std::cout << a+b << '\n';});
    A a2(f);
    B b1([a](int b){std::cout << a+b << '\n';});
    // B b2(f);
    a1.f(2);
    a2.f(2);
    b1.f(2);
    // b2.f(2);
    f(2);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
A(std::function<void(int)>&& func)
```

`A` can be initialized with `std::function` rvalue. Now, `f` (in `main`) *is not* a `std::function`, seeing as each lambda has its own distinct type. But we can create a temporary `std::function` out of it, and bind the rvalue reference `func` to that.

```
B(F&& func)
```

Don't let appearances fool you. This may look like a forwarding reference, but it isn't. Forwarding references are syntactically rvalue reference to a template parameter, but it must be a template parameter of the function we are forwarding into.

The constructor of `B` is not a template, and so `func` is not a forwarding reference.

The deduction guide that gets generated from that constructor accepts only rvalues, and deduces `F` from that. Because `f` (the local lambda in `main`) is an lvalue, it cannot bind to an rvalue reference and so CTAD cannot succeed. Indeed `std::move(f)` will make `b2` well-formed.

If you want to accept lvalues for arguments as well, you may add another constructor

```
B(F const& func) : f(func) {}
```

Now there are two deduction guides being generated, one for each value category.

Comment: The problem with adding another constructor is that, in order to be thorough, I think I need 6 constructors. At least, that is what `unique_ptr` has, see #3-#4 here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr. I don't actually understand what they all are

Comment: @Baruch - I don't understand what unique_ptr has to do with it. For one, it has a completely different function. Furthermore, it doesn't even *permit* CTAD with those constructors

Comment: What I meant was that unique_ptr accepts a callable as a templated type, and in order to do this in the best manner, it needs to account for 6 different combinations of template type and passed parameter type

Comment: @Baruch - Again, those constructors are unrelated to CTAD, so to derive conclusions from them is foolish. Rather than trying to mimic a component whose full requirements you don't understand, try to lay out all the requirements of your own component instead. Two constructors already produce a lot of mileage, and `F` will never be deduced as a reference type. If you are worried about explicit reference types being given and bypassing CTAD, then that's easily resolvable too, but in another post.

Comment: CTAD to me was just a convenience, an afterthought. It was not a requirement. I didn't realize it had any impact on the question/answer

Comment: @Baruch - It had a big place in the question you asked (re-read it if you don't believe me). You may have another question in mind that goes beyond this one, but the answer only applies to what you asked. So again, if you have another question, [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score -3):

```
B b2(f);
```

`B` is not a **class**, or a **type**, it is a **template**. An object declaration in C++ is, basically a declaration: here's a type, and here's one or more objects of that type (or a derived type). A template is not a type. A template ***instantiation*** is a type.

```
std::vector b2;
```

This won't compile for the same reason your code will not compile. You have to specify the template parameter to instantiate a type, such as:

```
std::vector<int> b2;
```

The same reason explains your compilation error.

Having said that, a small change to your template ***will*** make it compile as long as your compiler supports C++17:

```
template <class F>
class B {
public:
    B(F func) : f(std::move(func)) {}

    F f;
};
```

A C++17 compiler will be able to deduce the template parameter [due to class template deduction guides](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) in C++17. And, it's possible that with a little bit of additional work (I haven't looked into it) it might be possible to fiddle a few things and make your original template also work in C++17.

Comment: `B(F&& func)` does not inhibit CTAD. This answer is off target

Comment: g++ 11 seems to disagree, and chokes on it. Perhaps it's a g++ bug.

Comment: It's no bug, it's just getting an lvalue where an rvalue is expected. You also seem to have **entirely** neglected why `A` works.

Comment: It would work only if the declaration gets changed to `B b2(std::move(f));`. As shown it will not work.

Comment: At times like these I mourn the demise of Usenet, where these kinds of discussions were held with no inhibitions and artificial constraints.

Comment: Bluster or not, don't be sure you would have liked it yourself if there had been no constraints

Comment: Oh, I would've loved it. From the early 1990s, until it faded into the background, there wasn't a single thread that I participated in which was not enjoyable. Every once in a while a good one in `comp.lang.c++` still pops up. And I see an occasional Stackoverflow regular in there.

Comment: Luckily, extinction befalls all such unpleasant discussion boards and individuals.

Comment: Not yet, in this case, and not for a while longer, at least.

Comment: I suggest adding explanation why CTAD fails on `b2` (something about CTAD not doing perfrect-forwarding without user-defined deduction guides, etc)). The first half of the answer feels a bit out of place - OP's using CTAD for other variables, so they clearly target C++17 or newer.